# Configuring maven-surefire plugin with reuseForks

Tags: java, maven, surefire

I have a Java project that gets built by Maven.

Tests are being executed by "Surefire".
I'd like to set the plugin's property `reuseForks` to "false" (due to memory issues), however i cannot seem to find where i should place this setting.

In the POM we use, there's no reference to surefire, i am not sure how it gets executed, or where i should configure it (is it being used as some default?)

The pom can be found here: [pom](http://pastebin.com/0XLRJy8q)

How can i configure the surefire plugin explicitly? and where should the "`reuseForks`" setting be placed?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing is to add the [following part](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) into your pom file:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.16</version>
          <configuration>
            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Depending on which version of the maven-surefire-plugin you are using it will not change anything, ca9se reuseForks is by default set to `true`.
Apart from that. You don't see a definition of the maven-surefire-plugin in your pom means you are using the defaults where the maven-surefire-plugin is bound to the test phase by [maven's super pom](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM) which defines different versions of maven-surefire-plugin which is depending on the maven version you are using.